# How to improve the performance of this code

Tags: performance, functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

I have implemented a code in Mathematica 9 to simulate a scattering problem, and I got really disappointed about its performance when compared to Matlab. Since I am a newbie in Mathematica, would someone give me clues here?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
integrand[k_, P0_, P1_, rho_, l_] = Module[{x, h},
   x = P1*l + P0*(1. - l) - rho;
   h = HankelH2[0, Norm[x, 2]*k];
   h
   ];
innerInt[k_, P0_, P1_, rho_] := Module[{d, r, v, x},
   d = Norm[P0 - P1, 2];(* distancia entre os pontos *)
   v = integrand[k, P0, P1, rho, x];
   r = NIntegrate[v, {x, 0, 1}]*d;
   r
   ];
solveSystemCylinder[segsStart_, segsEnd_, Ei_, k_, eta_] := 
  Module[{colocPts, r, x, t, eiVals},
   colocPts = (segsStart + segsEnd)/2;
   t[x_] := MapThread[innerInt[k, #1, #2, x] &, {segsStart, segsEnd}];
   r = Map[t, colocPts];
   eiVals = Map[Ei[#, k] &, colocPts];
   N[LinearSolve[r, eiVals]]
   ];
Ei[p_, k_] := Exp[I*k*First[p]];

k := 2*Pi/Lambda;
Lambda := 1;
raio := Lambda;
eta := 1;
ND := 30;(* num de divisões *)
pts := N[raio*{Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@ (Range[0, ND]*(2*Pi/ND))];
pts2 := ({0, 2*Lambda} + #) & /@ pts;
allPts := Join[pts, pts2];

startPts := Take[pts, Length[pts] - 1];
endPts := Take[pts, -(Length[pts] - 1)];

startPts2 := Take[pts2, Length[pts2] - 1];
endPts2 := Take[pts2, -(Length[pts2] - 1)];

(*resolve*)
Js = solveSystemCylinder[Join[startPts, startPts2], 
   Join[endPts, endPts2], Ei, k, eta];
```

Comment: You might be better asking this in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning